# Prove by induction that $\sin\left(x\right)\ldots \sin\left(2^{n}x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(2^{n+1}x\right)}{2^{n+1}\sin\left(x\right)}$

Tags: induction

Prove the identity by using the induction theorem: $$\sin\left(x\right)\sin\left(2x\right)\sin\left(4x\right)\ldots \sin\left(2^{n}x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(2^{n+1}x\right)}{2^{n+1}\sin\left(x\right)}$$.

Basic Step: $\sin\left(2x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(2^{2}x\right)}{2^{2}\sin\left(x\right)}$

Prove Case $S(n)$: $$S\left(n\right)$$

Assuming true: $$\sin\left(x\right)sin\left(2x\right)\sin\left(4x\right)\ldots \sin\left(2^{n+1}x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(2^{n+2}x\right)}{2^{n+2}\sin\left(x\right)}$$

LHS: $$\frac{\sin\left(2^{n+1}x\right)}{2^{n+1}\sin\left(x\right)}\text{·}\sin\left(2^{n+1}x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(2^{n+1}x\right)^{2}}{2^{n+1}\sin\left(x\right)}$$

What is the correct process in order to prove it by induction?

Comment: It would be so much easier to try & prove
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cdots \cos(2^n x)=\frac{\sin(2^{n+1}x)}{2^{n+1}\sin(x)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The assertion isn't true: Put $n=0$ and it says $\sin x = \frac {\sin 2x} {2\sin x}$.

Comment: And the one about the cosines has surely been asked and answered on this site before, so it might be good to do a search for it. Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066277/is-there-an-alternative-form-identity-for-prod-k-1m-cos2kx and the questions linked there.

Comment: Any thoughts about the comments, Diego?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.